# How to do an X-month rolling sum while accounting for missing values

Tags: sas

I have monthly returns data, `Return`, a date variable, `Price_Date`, and a firm identification variable, `Firm_ID`.

There are several years of returns data for multiple firms.

Some months are missing entirely (no values for any variables including the date).

Alternatively for some of the months that do exist (i.e. the date variable exists) the `return` variable and/or the `Firm_ID` variable have missing values (i.e. `.`).

I want to calculate a new variable that is the rolling X-month (e.g. 3 months, 12 months) sum of the returns (consecutive months).

The new variable, Rolling_Sum, should equal the current month's return plus the previous (X-1) months returns (for a total of X months of returns).

However I also want to take into account missing observations such that when any of the returns in any particular month's rolling sum are missing then the rolling sum for that month should return a missing value also.

How can I achieve this?

For example if I am finding the 3 month rolling return then the data for the variables, Date, Firm_ID, Returns, and Rolling_Sum might look as follows.

```
31JAN2014 FirmA 10 .
28Feb2014 FirmA 11 .
31Mar2014 FirmA 12 33
30Apr2014 FirmA . .
31May2013 FirmA 10 .
30Jun2014 FirmA 10 .
31Aug2014 FirmA 12 .
30Sep2014 FirmA 11 .
31Oct2014 FirmA 50 73
31Jan2014 FirmB 20 .
28Feb2014 FirmB 70 .
31Mar2014 FirmB 40 130
```

Notice that if a value is missing within the 3 month sum then the Rolling_Sum returns as missing (i.e ".") also (e.g. lines 1 & 2, and 4, 5 & 6 of the data). In addition, if an observation is missing then a consecutive 3 month rolling sum cannot be obtained so I would get a missing value as output also (e.g. lines 7 and 8 since July is missing). 
That is the kind of ideal output I am after.

Edit: All returns are already calculated as returns for the whole month.

Clarification: I am after the rolling sum for consecutive months not consecutive observations.

Comment: Please provide your sample data and ideal output.

Comment: @rbet, I have added sample data and ideal output above. Notice that if a value is missing within the 3 month sum then the Rolling_Sum returns as missing also (e.g. lines 1 & 2, and 4, 5 & 6 of the data). In addition, if an observation is missing then a consecutive 3 month rolling sum cannot be obtained so I would get a missing value as output also (e.g. lines 7 and 8 since July is missing).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to understand the objective.

1. Once the firm_id is missing, how do you want to calculate its rolling sum?
2. If one record is entirely missing, are you going to exclude it?

---

Assuming your data look like this:

```
data _t1;
input Price_date date9. Firm_ID $6. Return 4.;
format Price_date date9.;
cards;
01JAN2014 FirmA 200
02Feb2014 FirmA 220
03Mar2014 FirmA 250
17Apr2014 FirmA .
20May2014 FirmA 300
23Jun2014 FirmA 180
17Jul2014 FirmA 460
27Aug2014 FirmA 300
14Sep2014 FirmA 50
31Oct2014 FirmA 20
30Nov2014 FirmA 780
03Dec2014 FirmA 420
;
run;

data _t2;
set _t1;
Firm_ID = 'FirmB';
Return = coalesce(Return + 20,100);
if mod(_n_,5) = 0 then call missing(Return);
run;

data sample;
set _t1 _t2;
run;

proc print data=sample;run;
```

First sort it by `Firm_ID` then by `price_date`.

```
proc sort data=sample;by Firm_ID Price_date;run;

/* rolling 3 mths */
data want;
set sample;
Rolling_Sum  = Return + lag1(Return) + lag2(Return);
if first.Firm_ID then call missing(Rolling_Sum);
by Firm_ID Price_date;
run;
```

Comment: 1. If the firm_id is missing then it shouldn't be included in any of the rolling sums for any firm.
2. If an observation is missing entirely (i.e. a month is skipped) then it should be left out.
Also, is there a way to generalise it to compute the rolling sum over X months without manually changing the number of lag terms each time?

Comment: I would suggest you to look into `proc expand`.  It can be genealized by using macro variable `%let rolln = 12`.

Comment: How do I deal with missing observations? For example in your code if I delete the line for 14Sep2014 then the rolling sum is stall computed for October using the previous 3 observations, not the previous 3 consecutive months.

Answer (score 0):

`proc expand` is a very powerful and handy tool for creating clean time series output from messy input data. I read in your sample data into a dataset called returns with the variables date, firm_id, returns and desired_roll3. Using `proc expand`, will create missing dates with missing values and a new variable called calc_roll3 that matched the desired_roll3. Hopefully, the comments in code will provide enough commentary to understand how it works.

```
proc expand
   data=returns /* input dataset */
   out=returns2 /* output dataset */
   from=month   /* input timeframe - monthly */
   align=end    /* alignment of timeframe - end of month */
;
by firm_id; * each time series is grouped by firm_id;
id date; * specify time series variable;
convert returns / method=none;  * do not interpolate missing values;
* calculate 3-period moving sum without missing values, and set the first 2 values at ;
* beginning of each by-group to missing;
convert returns=calc_roll3 / method=none transformout=(nomiss movsum 3 trimleft 2);
run;
```

Here's the new dataset.

[image]